# Send data whit WebSockets on C# and JS

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

I am trying to send data from c # to js with websockets, so they look for example send an alert when activating a function from C # but I can not make a successful connection to send and receive the data, this is my code js

```
var ws;
var reconnectTimer;

function connect() {
  ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + host + ':' + port + '/');

  ws.onopen = function() {
    clearInterval(reconnectTimer);
    console.log('Conexión WebSockets establecida');
  };

  ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    if (!e.data || e.data.length === 0 || e.data === '')
      return;

    console.log('Recibiendo: ' + e.data);

    var message = JSON.parse(e.data);

    if (message.Name === undefined)
      return;

    if (!handlers.has(message.Name))
      return;

    if (message.Arguments === undefined)
      message.Arguments = [];

    handlers.get(message.Name)(ws, message.Arguments, message);
  };

  ws.onclose = function() {
    console.log('Conexión WebSockets no establecida, esperando reconexión');
    clearInterval(reconnectTimer);
    reconnectTimer = setInterval(reconnect, 3000);
  };
}

function reconnect() {
  console.log('Reconectando WebSockets...');
  ws.close();
  ws = undefined;
  connect();
}

connect();

function sendMessage(handlerName, args) {
  var jsonMessage = {
    Name: handlerName,
    Arguments: args
  };
  var message = JSON.stringify(jsonMessage);
  console.log('Enviando: ' + message);
  ws.send(message);
}
```

I'm using "Fleck" in C#, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: in many browsers you can see the WS frames; what is happening at the WS level? if it isn't in your browser, tools like Fiddler or WireShark can do the same; so: is it actually connecting? if it isn't, the js code won't matter...

Comment: Yes, yes connecting